# MySQL: save JSON data via stored procedure in Node.js

Tags: mysql, sql, json, stored-procedures, mysql-json

I am trying to save some JSON data with a stored procedure in MySQL and Node.

I have `post`, `post_tag` and `tag` tables.

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS post_tag;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS post;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tag;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS select_all_posts;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insert_post;

CREATE TABLE post (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  body TEXT NULL,
  my_data TEXT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE tag (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  tag VARCHAR(45) NULL UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE post_tag (
  post_id INT NOT NULL,
  tag_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (post_id, tag_id),
  INDEX fk_post_tag_tag1_idx (tag_id ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX fk_post_tag_post_idx (post_id ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT fk_post_tag_post
    FOREIGN KEY (post_id)
    REFERENCES post (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_post_tag_tag1
    FOREIGN KEY (tag_id)
    REFERENCES tag (id));

INSERT INTO post (id, title, body) VALUES (1, 'post 1', "Post body");
INSERT INTO post (id, title, body) VALUES (2, 'post 2', "Post body");
INSERT INTO tag (id, tag) VALUES (1, 'tag 1');
INSERT INTO tag (id, tag) VALUES (2, 'tag 2');
INSERT INTO post_tag (post_id, tag_id) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO post_tag (post_id, tag_id) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO post_tag (post_id, tag_id) VALUES (2, 1);
```

Now I want to save one post with two tags, so I created this stored procedure:

```sql
-- Stored procedure to insert post and tags
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insert_post;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_post(
  IN my_data JSON
)
BEGIN
  -- Declare iterator variable to use it later on in the loop
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;

  -- Retrieve values from JSON
  SET @title = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(my_data, '$.title'));
  SET @body = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(my_data, '$.body'));
  SET @tags = JSON_EXTRACT(my_data, '$.tags');
  SET @json = JSON_UNQUOTE(my_data);
  -- Insert post
  INSERT INTO post (title, body, my_data) VALUES (
    @title,
    @body,
    @json);
  -- Retrieve inserted id to reuse it in post_tag
  SET @last_post = LAST_INSERT_ID();

  -- Get tags length for the loop
  SET @tags_length = JSON_LENGTH(@tags);
  -- Execute loop over tags length
  WHILE i < @tags_length DO
    -- Retrieve current tag from tags array
    SET @tag = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(my_data, CONCAT('$.tags[',i,'].tag')));

    -- Insert tag
    INSERT INTO tag (tag) VALUES (
    @tag
    ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tag = @tag;
    -- -- Retrieve inserted tag to reuse it on post_tag
    SET @last_tag = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    -- Insert retrieved post_id and tag_id into post_tag
    INSERT INTO post_tag (post_id, tag_id) VALUES (
      @last_post,
      @last_tag
    ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE post_id = @last_post, tag_id = @last_tag;
    -- -- Add step to iterator
    SELECT i + 1 INTO i;
  END WHILE;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

I can test it with SQL directly:

```sql
CALL insert_post('{"title":"My post","body":"postbody","tags":[{"tag":"tag 3"}]}');
```

This will succeed, as there are no repeated tags.

```sql
CALL insert_post('{"title":"My post","body":"postbody","tags":[{"tag":"tag 1"}]}');
```

This will fail, as there is already a `tag 1`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: JSON_UNQUOTE()? REPLACE()?

Comment: Hi @Akina, don't understand exactly what you mean. How would you use REPLACE here?

Comment: Just found out that its now a problem with JSON_UNQUOTE, but with post_tag having two keys and ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_post(
  IN my_data JSON
)
BEGIN
  -- Declare iterator variable to use it later on in the loop
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;

  -- Retrieve values from JSON
  SET @title = JSON_EXTRACT(my_data, '$.title');
  SET @body = JSON_EXTRACT(my_data, '$.body');
  SET @tags = JSON_EXTRACT(my_data, '$.tags');
  SET @json = JSON_UNQUOTE(my_data);
  -- Insert post
  INSERT INTO post (title, body, my_data) VALUES (
-- ****    UNQUOTE values    ****
    JSON_UNQUOTE(@title),
    JSON_UNQUOTE(@body),
    @json);
  -- Retrieve inserted id to reuse it in post_tag
  SET @last_post = LAST_INSERT_ID();

  -- Get tags length for the loop
  SET @tags_length = JSON_LENGTH(@tags);
  -- Execute loop over tags length
  WHILE i < @tags_length DO
    -- Retrieve current tag from tags array
    SET @tag = JSON_EXTRACT(my_data, CONCAT('$.tags[',i,'].tag'));

    -- Insert tag
    INSERT INTO tag (tag) VALUES (
-- ****    UNQUOTE value    ****
      JSON_UNQUOTE(@tag)
    ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tag = JSON_UNQUOTE(@tag);
    -- Retrieve inserted tag to reuse it on post_tag
-- ****    ODKU and LAST_INSERT_ID are not relative!!! removed.    ****
--    SET @last_tag = LAST_INSERT_ID();
-- ****    Retrieve according `id`    ****
    SELECT id INTO @last_tag
    FROM tag
    WHERE tag = JSON_UNQUOTE(@tag);
    -- Insert retrieved post_id and tag_id into post_tag
    INSERT INTO post_tag (post_id, tag_id) VALUES (
      @last_post,
      @last_tag
    ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE post_id = @last_post, tag_id = @last_tag;
    -- Add step to iterator
    SELECT i + 1 INTO i;
  END WHILE;
END
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3f2627e8642f8e1dce155de32385e10e)

PS. You may use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tag = VALUES(tag);` instead of `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tag = JSON_UNQUOTE(@tag);`. And the same for `post_tag`. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=34ecdc511ce1efc26c31f71905595827).

Comment: Interesting! What do you mean with «LAST_INSERT_ID are not relative»?

Comment: also, what is `ODKU`?

Comment: @EmilleC. You try to insert. If no duplicate, insertion performed, new `id` generated and then retrieved. But what if duplicate was detected? Update performed instead. Does INSERT was performed? no. Does last inserted `id` was generated and it exists now? no. `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will return zero. Which results foreing key violatoin. *what is ODKU* ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE abbreviation.

Comment: really good explanation: update doesn't generate `LAST_INSERT_ID()`… Thanks!